# Trying to include a file, file_exists is essential?

Tags: php, include, file-exists

Sorry for possiblely reduplicate asking. But it's hard to use this confusable keyword to search a answer.

So here is scenario:

I try to get a advise to make my simple autoloader. Here is i made so far:

```
private function getAutoInclude($classfile) {
    $classfileLower = strtolower($classfile);

    if (isset($this->configs['Paths']['base.'.$classfileLower])) { // Use path scope to locate file first
        return require_once($this->configs['Paths']['base.'.$classfileLower]['Path']);
    } elseif ($this->configs['LibRoot'] && strpos($classfile, '\\') !== false) { // If above not work, use namespace to locate file
        return require_once($this->configs['LibRoot'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace(array('\\', '/', '_'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ltrim($classfile, '\\')) . '.php');
    }

    return false;
}
```

It works well so far but only thing confused me is, some people tells me i must to do a  file_exists check on the file i'm including so i can include it more safer AND more faster.

So consider the file i want to included must be there each time i include it, will i really have to file_exists in this scenario or not?

(I know this question just like a newbie asked. But when i heard people say if file_exists can make file include faster, it break some of my knowledge on PHP.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705179/file-exists-vs-suppressed-include-which-is-the-faster-way-to-fail-in-php

Comment: @Ben, The question actually has two situations: File existed or not. Mines only have one. And i'm not suppressed errors.

Comment: @Ben, I did another test on this scenario and result is, without file_exists is.... more faster a little bit in avg time. Consider i'm not suppress anything (it just die), i think without file_exists is make sencely more faster. Thank you for point the link of that question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are including is required.  (Presumably anyway... you are using `require_once()`.)  If the file isn't there, your script will fail.  No need for all this checking and nonsense, just do the `require_once()` call.

Also, add your paths to the include path.  Let PHP figure it out.  No need to write code to search for a file.

Comment: The path scope i made is for support to load those modules not in framework core or project directory, like common library.

Comment: @RainLee, Right.  Add it to the include path.

Comment: The order you list your paths in the include_path is important, list those that are going to get the most include calls first because there is a little overhead associated with each path the server needs to check before finding the correct one. So in your case you probably want your framework directory listed first and then let it fallback onto the others.

Answer (score 0):

just use the __autoload() function and save yourself the stress because if those files you're requiring are nonexistence then you're i trouble of getting those red table error report